# Find 3 normal variables which are linear combinations based on 3 ind std normal variable given a correlation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, correlation

I am given $3$ normal random variables $X_1$,$X_2$,$X_3$ which are linear combinations of $Z_1$,$Z_2$,$Z_3$. $Z_1$,$Z_2$,$Z_3$ are mutually independent standard normal variables.

I am given a correlation matrix

$$X=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0.3 & 0.4  \\0.3 & 1 & 0.5  \\0.4 & 0.5 & 1  \end{bmatrix}$$

I have to find $M$ which is $3 \times 3$ such that

$$\begin{bmatrix} X_1   \\X_2   \\X_3  \\ \end{bmatrix}
=M \cdot\begin{bmatrix} Z_1   \\Z_2   \\Z_3  \\ \end{bmatrix}$$

---

Any hints on how to approach this, based on my research , I am getting a stong correlation
 of google hits on multivariate normal distribution and cholesky method, but I am still not
 able to relate how cholesky method will help if it is M would be relevant.

octave-3.2.4.exe:10> Q3

Q3 =

1.00000   0.30000   0.40000

0.30000   1.00000   0.50000

0.40000   0.50000   1.00000

octave-3.2.4.exe:11> chol(Q3)

ans =

1.00000   0.30000   0.40000

0.00000   0.95394   0.39835

0.00000   0.00000   0.82542

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Unrelated to the Math in the question: Please go through the Edits I have made to your post. It might be of help the next time you post here.

Answer (score 1):

The correlation matrix of $Z_1,Z_2,Z_3$ is the identity matrix. You get the correlation matrix of $X_1,X_2,X_3$ from this by multiplying by $M$ from the left and $M^\top$ from the right. Thus the correlation matrix of $X_1,X_2,X_3$ is $MM^\top$. Cholesky decomposition gives you a matrix $M$ such that $MM^\top$ is a given matrix. Note that this is only one solution, the one in which $M$ is lower triangular; you can right-multiply this $M$ by any orthogonal matrix to get another solution.